# How to modify the selector * of css through javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if it is possible to modify the "*" selector of css by means of javascript or jquery.

For example, I have the following:

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

And I need to modify by means of javascript or jquery "font-family".

Comment: You could append a new rule programmatically, but it may be just simpler to set this rule on a common ancestor, like `document.documentElement` or `document.body` since font-family is an inherited property.

Comment: document.body.childNodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, * selects all elements. So, all HTML elements should be in the body, right? So, when you change it, change the whole body instead of all elements.

```
$('body').CSS({'font-family':})
```

or

```
$('*').CSS({'font-family':})
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should select the elements of DOM. Then we can do anything what we want by using javascript as follows.

`getElementsByTagName("*")` will return all elements from DOM.

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, len = allElements.length; i < len; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];
    // Change any style you want 
    // Ex- element.style.border = ...
}
```

Ref : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

Answer (score 3):

Just the same stuff your selector would be `*`...

So do `$("*").css({"font-family": "Arial"});` if using jQuery...

But pure **JavaScript,** you can do:

```
document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(el => el.style.fontFamily = "Arial");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following in pure Javascript:

```
 var everything = document.querySelectorAll("*");

 for(var i=0; i < everything.length; i++) {
     everything[i].style.fontFamily = "Arial";
     //add your CSS styles here
 }
```

This will loop through every element in the DOM and add the CSS.

Or if you are using Jquery, there is way easier method to do it.
See below

```
  $("*").css("font-family","Arial");
```

or just simply style the body

```
$("body").css("font-family","Arial");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have access to your style sheets fom JS and change them directly (not by filter/change any html nodes) more info [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript).

```js
let rules=document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;

let rule= [...rules].find(r=> r.selectorText=="*" );

rule.style.fontFamily="cursive";
```

```css
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
Example test

<div style="font-family: 'Roboto'">No font change</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("*").css({"font-family": "your-font"});
```